# How to set Parent and Sub-menu class as active

Tags: php, css, arrays, json

Current Issue: Getting Parent and Sub-menu class as active.

Bassically, I have a json array with my current page layout. I want to cycle through the array and find if it matches with the current page. For some reason it simply does not match and when I do get it to match it outputs the page name not "active" or "_active" ?

Any better ways of doing this would be much appreciated :)

json page array:

```
{
    "Pages":{
        "Home":"Dashboard",
        "USD Market":{
            "Current-Trades":"USD-Current-Trades",
            "Exchange-Trades":"USD-Exchange-Trades"
        }
    }
}
```

in page header:

```
<?php   
    $directoryURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $path = parse_url($directoryURI, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $components = explode('/', $path);
    $pagename = $components[1];
?>
```

function:

```
    public function pages($pagename)
{
    if ($pagename == array($config['Pages']))
    {
        print 'yes';
    } else {
        print 'no';
    }
}
```

Menu:

```
            <div class="menu">
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
                <li class="<?php print $dash->pages($pagename); ?>">
                    <a href="/Dashboard">
                        <i class="material-icons">home</i>
                        <span>Home</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle">
                        <i class="material-icons">trending_down</i>
                        <span>USD ($) - Market Trades</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="ml-menu">
                        <li class="<?php print $dash->pages($pagename); ?>">
                            <a href="/USD-Current-Trades">
                                <span>Current Trades</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <span>Exchange Trades</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Thank you for any input provided :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `public function pages()`, you check this:

```
if ($pagename == array($config['Pages']))
```

But `$config` is never defined in that method, nor is it passed in, so it will always be false. If you look in your error_log you will probably see a notice, if you have your error_reporting set. (Set error_reporting to -1!)

I guess you meant to `json_decode($json, true)` somewhere, and pass that in as a second argument.

```
<?php

$pages = json_decode('{
    "Pages":{
        "Home":"Dashboard",
        "USD Market":{
            "Current-Trades":"USD-Current-Trades",
            "Exchange-Trades":"USD-Exchange-Trades"
        }
    }
}', true);

class Z
{
    private $pages;

    private $currentPage;

    public function setConfig($currentPage, array $config)
    {
        $this->currentPage = $currentPage;
        $this->pages = [];
        $this->addToPageList($config['Pages']);
    }

    public function pages($linkName)
    {
        return $this->pages[$linkName];
    }

    public function addToPageList(array $pages)
    {
        foreach ($pages as $key => $page) {
            if (is_array($page)) {
                $this->addToPageList($page);
            } else {
                $active = ($page == $this->currentPage) ? 'active' : 'inactive';
                $this->pages[$page] = $active;
            }
        }
    }
}

$z = new Z();
$z->setConfig('USD-Exchange-Trades', $pages); // current page, page config
echo $z->pages('USD-Exchange-Trades') . "\n";
echo $z->pages('USD-Current-Trades') . "\n";
echo $z->pages('Dashboard') . "\n";
```

Output:

```
active 
inactive 
inactive
```

Play with it here https://3v4l.org/PtAiF

Comment: `$config` is defined in another file and it is called using require_once `$config = json_decode($json, true);`, it is being called in the functions page.

Comment: Okay, but it is never passed into that class method, meaning it's out of scope, and inaccessible.

Comment: Could you perhaps set me off in the correct direction on how to parse it into the classes function ?

Comment: adjust your method to take a second argument as updated, then wherever you call `pages($pageName)`, add the config!

Comment: Is there perhaps a better way to do this?. As I am stuck with the parent name being `$config['Pages]['USD Market']` and the sub-menu being `$config['Pages']['USD Market']['USD-Current-Trades']` I need to make both classes active only is the sub-menu class is active.

Comment: I need to loop though the `$config['Pages']` to find if  a page is active in `$config['USD Market']` and its sub-menu.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer! This should work for you!

Comment: tried your updated answer and my old menu needs to have to functions inputted so I used `<li class="<?php print $dash->pages($pagename,$config); ?>">`, I checked the home page. It now lights up all the menu items, although when I go into a page in sets it as "_active" (instead of leaving it blank I used _active). in the log file I get this error for the function that you made `PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type `

Comment: Hi again. Yes I see my error, theres an array inside an array, I've completely changed the code, let me update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171972/discussion-between-jamesbond-and-delboy1978uk).

Comment: chat is blocked in this office. edited anyway, that should sort you out :)

Comment: I tried everything and used `setConfig(); to set the pagename and config. then I used `<li class="<?php print $dash->pages($pagename); ?>">` . When I had a look at the page it seems to light up the entire menu still. when I enter USD-Current-Trades page nothing lights up on the menu ?

Comment: its weird since the menu is dynamic and all pages call for the exact same menu

Comment: Don't pass the same pagename in for each link! For each link, put the actual page key, so for the home page dashboard link for instance it would be `$z->pages('Dashboard')`

Comment: Awesome, that worked with the sub menu. It lights the correct pages up. Although it does not light up the parent menu when the sub-menu is lit. I used this on the parent menu to fix that issue `<li class="<?php if ($dash->pages('USD-Current-Trades') == 'active' || $dash->pages('USD-Exchange-Trades') == 'active') { print 'active'; } else { print 'inactive'; } ?>">`